# Ивент discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

### Event Discord Code [#Error]

---

Пытаюсь создать команду для эмбеда с реакциями на голосование.
Скиньте код плз.

[image: Вид]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@client.command( pass_context = True )
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def startvote(ctx, *, arg):
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'Начато голосование на ивент',
    description='Ивент: ' + str(arg),
    colour=discord.Color.purple()
    )
    message = await ctx.send(embed=emb) 
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
    print('>>Sent message about voting of event. Name of event: ' + str(arg))
```